# Video playing in ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to play video in my asp.net page. I am using the code

```
<object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" id="Player1" width="440" height="379">
          <param name="URL" value="~/DBVideo/citibank.mpeg">
          <param name="http://">
          <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
          <param name="ShowControls" value="">
          <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1">
          <param name="ShowDisplay" value="1">
          <param name="stretchToFit" value="1">
              <param name="volume" value="32" />
              <embed runat="server" id="Video"
              type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" 
             width="440" height="379" src="~/DBVideo/citibank.mpeg"
              filename="~/DBVideo/citibank.mpeg" autostart="1" showcontrols="1" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1">
              </embed>
       </object>
```

Now only the media player symbol is coming but the video is not playing.

Can anybody help me where the problem is??
and if I want to play the video from SQL server 2008 database (varbinary field) then what would I do?

Comment: Are you allowed to use HTML5?

Comment: no. Is there anything wrong i my code?

Comment: hmm. I used exactly the same html code and used file from here http://www.fileformat.info/format/mpeg/sample/index.htm and it played in IE9 and Chrome (with extension)

Comment: Also: in your HTML above ASP.NET cant't resolve path "~/DBVideo/citibank.mpeg" You should probably use <%= ResolveClientUrl("~/DBVideo/citibank.mpeg")%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to use HTML5, you can use video tag

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

As for getting video from sql: you can use http handler which extracts file from SQL and probably caches it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: its working @Andriy F. But, how can I play video from database

Comment: How about try extracting it from database to some folder first and then play it?